# How can I plot the Core at cooperative game by latex?

Tags: graphs, game-tree

Consider a game of a function v which has floowing ways

$V(1)>= 12$

$V(2)>= 7$

$V(3)>= 10$

$V(1,2)>= 128$

$V(1,3)>= 185$

$V(2,3)>= 18$

$V(1,2,3)=300$

How can I plot such a function in latex(preferably in 2D).

For example, it is like below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you want something that computes and draws the solution. If that were the case LaTeX might not be the best option.

If you only want to draw the solution (that you already obtained) this is an approach that does a great part of the task.

I define some macros that draw the lines at x, y or z constant, and their labels. These macros use (scaled) barycentric coordinates, easier this way. I'm including the `siunitx` package because in some problems (e.g. some of your examples) you might not have entire numbers. In that case you'll probably want to change all the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` for `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2,round-pad=false}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xconst}{O{red}mmmm} % #1 = color (red), #2 = x value, #3 = coordinates name, #4,#5 = nodes format
{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\x{#2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\yz{\xyz-\x}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xs{\x/\xyz} % x scaled
  \draw[#1] (barycentric cs:X=\xs,Y=0,Z=1-\xs) coordinate (#31) node[left ,#4] {$(\num{\x},0,\num{\yz})$} --
            (barycentric cs:X=\xs,Y=1-\xs,Z=0) coordinate (#32) node[below,#5] {$(\num{\x},\num{\yz},0)$}; 
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\yconst}{O{red}mmmm} % #1 = color (red), #2 = y value, #3 = coordinates name, #4,#5 = nodes format
{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{#2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xz{\xyz-\y}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ys{\y/\xyz} % y scaled
  \draw[#1] (barycentric cs:X=0,Y=\ys,Z=1-\ys) coordinate (#31) node[right,#4] {$(0,\num{\y},\num{\xz})$} --
            (barycentric cs:X=1-\ys,Y=\ys,Z=0) coordinate (#32) node[below,#5] {$(\num{\xz},\num{\y},0)$}; 
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\zconst}{O{red}mmmm} % #1 = color (red), #2 = z value, #3 = coordinates name, #4,#5 = nodes format
{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\z{#2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xy{\xyz-\z}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\zs{\z/\xyz} % z scaled
  \draw[#1] (barycentric cs:X=0,Y=1-\zs,Z=\zs) coordinate (#31) node[right,#4] {$(0,\num{\xy},\num{\z})$} --
            (barycentric cs:X=1-\zs,Y=0,Z=\zs) coordinate (#32) node[left ,#5] {$(\num{\xy},0,\num{\z})$}; 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \def\r{4};                 % tiangle side
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xyz{300}; % great coalition payoff
  % triangle coordinates
  \coordinate  (X) at (210:\r);
  \coordinate  (Y) at (330:\r);
  \coordinate  (Z) at  (90:\r);
  % lines
  \xconst{12} {X} {}{left,rotate=90}                        % x >= 12
  \yconst{7}  {Y} {}{left,rotate=90}                        % x >= 7
  \zconst{10} {Z} {yshift=-1mm}{yshift=-1mm}                % z >= 10
  \zconst{172}{XY}{yshift=-1mm}{yshift=-1mm}                % x + y >= 128 ==> z <= 172
  \yconst{115}{XZ}{yshift=1mm} {left,rotate=90}             % x + z >= 185 ==> y <= 115
  \xconst{282}{YZ}{yshift=2mm} {left,rotate=90,yshift=-1mm} % y + z >= 18  ==> x <= 282
  % core
  \fill[red,fill opacity=0.3] (X1) -- (X2) -- (YZ2) -- (YZ1) -- cycle;
  \fill[red,fill opacity=0.3] (Y1) -- (Y2) -- (XZ2) -- (XZ1) -- cycle;
  \fill[red,fill opacity=0.3] (Z1) -- (Z2) -- (XY2) -- (XY1) -- cycle;
  % triangle
  \draw[thick] (X) node[below left]  {$(\xyz,0,0)$} --
               (Y) node[below right] {$(0,\xyz,0)$} --
               (Z) node[above]       {$(0,0,\xyz)$} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the core:
[image]

Comment: Much appreciated